# My greek symbols look different

Tags: fonts

I don't know why my greek symbols in latex look different from usual documents.

For example, alpha and omega look like the first picture.

However, mine shows like the second picture.

How can I make mine as normal?

What package do I have to use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: symbols look different in different fonts. You haven't given any information about which font you use so we cannot help further.

Comment: Which package do you use? It looks like boldface greek letters

Comment: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

I use the following package. What should I change?

Comment: mathptmx (delete this)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much!

Comment: To explain David Carlisle’s great comment a bit, `mathptmx` is an (obsolete) package that changes the math font to Times. You get the default font if you don’t load any packages that change it.